# Inserting a tab in Vim through a bind works only one time

Tags: vim, config, indentation, key-bindings

I've made an Insert mode bind (opening curly bracket + Enter) which enters a tab (4 spaces) on the next line and a closing curly bracket after.

```
inoremap {<Enter> {<Enter><Enter>}<Up><Tab>
```

The example:

```
fn foo() {
    // Some code
}
```

It works fine, but when I try to use the bind again it won't insert tabs anymore, just a new line and a bracket.

```
fn bar() {
    if condition {
    loop {
    // Some more code
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Probably you want to edit and add a clearer question?

Comment: Thanks for telling me! Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Looks like it is entering a tab each time.  One single tab.  It's just not adding an additional tab for each level of scope that.  By initially skipping that first line after the bracket, vim is assuming that line is blank and isn't keeping the auto-indent tab on that line, so when you go back up to it and hit Tab, it leaves you with one level of indentation on that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to insert that `<Tab>` yourself:

```
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<C-o>O
```

`O` will open a new line above the current line, with the right amount and type of indentation.

Comment: Provided some `indent` like autoindent is set

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but I think this might accomplish your goal:

`inoremap {<Enter> {<Enter><Tab><Enter>}<Esc><<<Up>A`

**Edit**: there was previously a typo in my solution.  Try again if it didn't work originally

Comment: or use `<c-o>` e.g. `inoremap {<cr> {<cr>}<c-o>O`

Comment: You're missing the all-important indent in your alternative here

Comment: Well, turns out I don't even need to indent by myself and the solution in the comment works.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend using an abbreviation instead so you don't have a weird delay.

The following uses "rails.vim" like `RailsExpand` function. Put inside of `vimrc` file:

```
function! RailsExpand(root, good, ...)
  let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
  echom c
  if c == "" || c =~ (a:0 ? a:1 : "\t")
    return a:good
  else
    return a:root . c
  endif
endfunction

iabbrev { <c-r>=RailsExpand('{', "{\<lt>cr>}\<lt>c-o>O\<tab>", '\r')<cr>
```

Personally, I prefer to expand on `<tab>` instead of `<cr>` so you could use:

```
iabbrev { <c-r>=RailsExpand('{', "{\<lt>cr>}\<lt>c-o>O\<tab>")<cr>
```